# Puppet module using join works in production but breaks tests

Tags: puppet

I have a module which includes the line:

```
join(lookup('latest_packages'),"\n")
```

In production it works but I'm trying to re-structure the module based on the template from `puppet module generate`, including the tests.

When I run `rake spec` I get back:

```
  1) custom_facts with default values for all parameters should contain Class[custom_facts]
     Failure/Error: it { should contain_class('custom_facts') }

     Puppet::PreformattedError:
       Evaluation Error: Unknown function: 'join'. at /home/philip/projects/control-repo-globals/modules/custom_facts/spec/fixtures/modules/custom_facts/manifests/init.pp:8:16 on node philip-thinkpad-t420.lan
```

How can I access the join function from inside the tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by creating a `.fixtures.yml` that included the standard puppet library:

```
fixtures:
  repositories:
    stdlib: git://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib.git
```

Answer (score 1):

This is often caused by Puppet not finding the Ruby Lib that contains your Puppet functions.

Try adding to your `spec/spec_helper.rb` something like:

```
$LOAD_PATH << './modules/lib'
```

Comment: `join` actually comes from `stdlib`, so while this works if he wrote the function himself, in this case he needs to put `stdlib` into his module `fixtures` so the function is even available to load.